# how to use Use Google Authentication for Java webportal with SSO

Tags: java, google-authentication

I am new to GA(OAuth).

I have few queries while using Google authentication on java web based portal. 1) How and where do I configure my web-portal(e.g. https://abc.xyz.com)?

2) If I have 100 user base, in that case do i have to create each user's account in order to achieve authentication from Google? If yes then how shall i map them for above portal?

3) I have used I used http://ocpsoft.org/java/setting-up-google-oauth2-with-java/ Is there any way to avoid maintenance of clientID, Clientsecret or JSon at my web application level and can still achieve secure authentication from GA?

4) how can i implement SSO along with GA in java web application? 
Any early help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You would configure your web portal details in https://code.google.com/apis/console/ .   Using the left menu 'API Access' > 'Create Client ID'.

2) You need not have to configure for every users. Every time they access your application they would login with their own google account.

3) No you can't avoid Client ID & client secret. They are needed for this functionality to work.

Read more on https://developers.google.com/console/help/?csw=1#UsingOAuth2

Comment: Thnaks regarding to point no.2,
How Do I differentiate user having valid google account but not valid for my web portal?
Do I also have to take overhead of maintaining passwords of users at my end so i can authenticate them before sending request to GA with client ID and secret?
Please let me know if i am not sounding correct

Comment: Jay , any suggestions on above question?